# List running services along with EXECSTART command

Tags: systemd

My main goal is to be able to find the service linked with a given process id assuming process was started by a service. In this direction, I'm trying to find a way to list all running services along with there EXECSTART command or it's pid so I could use grep after to narrow down. Please help me out.

Comment: Does `systemctl status <PID>` help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Something like `systemctl list-units --no-pager -ql --type=service --state=running | awk '{printf "%s\0", $1}' | xargs -r0  systemctl show --no-pager -qP ExecStart --`?